# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib._parallel_backends'

Tags: python, joblib

I am trying to import `joblib` but got this error.

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import joblib

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\labelme\lib\site-packages\joblib\__init__.py:120, in <module>
    118 from .numpy_pickle import load
    119 from .compressor import register_compressor
--> 120 from .parallel import Parallel
    121 from .parallel import delayed
    122 from .parallel import cpu_count

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\labelme\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:26, in <module>
     24 from .logger import Logger, short_format_time
     25 from .disk import memstr_to_bytes
---> 26 from ._parallel_backends import (FallbackToBackend, MultiprocessingBackend,
     27                                  ThreadingBackend, SequentialBackend,
     28                                  LokyBackend)
     29 from .externals.cloudpickle import dumps, loads
     30 from .externals import loky

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib._parallel_backends'
```

I also located to that folder and did not found any `_parallel_backends.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to incompatible version of `joblib`. Downgrading the version from `1.1.0` to `1.0.0` solved the problem.

```
pip install joblib==1.0.0
```